# Citations in abstract

Tags: research-process, citations, writing

I am interested to know about rules in writing abstract in social sciences. Is it wrong if you just cited in the abstract around two key authors of frameworks where your study was based? Then citations were avoided for the rest of the abstract?

Comment: I don't know about social sciences, but I learned an abstract is there for potential readers to decide if it is worth to read something without having to read up on anything else/ having to have an understanding of other studies in the field. It is supposed to make them want to read what you wrote, even if they are not knowledgable of or interested in the framework you based your study on.

Comment: I think you should also keep in mind that some Journals put the references behind a paywall so they might not be accessible to readers of the abstract.

Comment: @user93559: Maybe that's field-specific, but I have a really hard time imagining a situation where I am pondering whether or not to get access to a paper that is paywalled to me, and where that decision hinges on a piece of information that I can only obtain by having access to a reference mentioned in the abstract.